# Get properties from object in tag

Tags: c#, .net, chess

For a School assignment we are making a Chess game in C#, in which we have to learn to work in a Object-Oriented way. The board is made out of a 2D picturebox array in a nested for loop

```
//Create the Board Pattern out of PictureBoxes
        #region Checkerboard

        PictureBox[,] Vak = new PictureBox[8, 8];

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
            {

                Vak[i, x] = new PictureBox();
                Vak[i, x].Name = String.Format("{0},{1}", i, x);
                Vak[i, x].Width = 50;
                Vak[i, x].Height = 50;
                Vak[i, x].Location = new Point(xpos, ypos);
                Vak[i, x].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                Vak[i, x].Click += Chess_Click;
                if ((i + x) % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Vak[i, x].BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e5e5e5");  //white ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e5e5e5");
                }
                else
                {
                    Vak[i, x].BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#545454"); //black ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#545454");

                }
                xpos += 50;
                this.Controls.Add(Vak[i, x]);
            }
            xpos = 50;
            ypos += 50;
            this.Controls.Add(border);
        }
        #endregion
```

On other posts i have found that i can Refer to a class (via the picturebox) using the .Tag property like so:

```
Vak[i,x].Tag = new Tower();
```

However, i cannot figure out a way to call properties from the Tower class from withing the tag

Say the Tower class has a property "name", how would i go about calling that

```
string objectname = Vak[i,x].Tag.(name?)
```

Sorry If this is a stupid question, but i am very new to programming.
Thanks!

Comment: If you know the type of the object that you're storing in the `Tag` property, you'll need to cast it explicitly to that type to access its properties. Something like `((Tower)(Vak[i, x])).Name`.

Comment: I would recommend not to use the `Tag` property, but instead create your own struct with a picturebox and a chesspiece member.

Comment: @Wimmel And how exactly would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 6):

You have to cast it, since Tag is an Object type:

```
Tower tower = Vak[i,x].Tag as Tower;

if(tower!=null)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

However,  i would avoid storing data structures in Tag properties like this.

Comment: And what if it is not a `Tower`?